# What is the Schrodinger equation's dynamics when having classical and statistical mechanics in mind?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, probability

Assume I take the following PDE without QM associated with it.
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(\mathbf{r},t) = \left [ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r},t)\right ] \Psi(\mathbf{r},t)
$$

What kind of dynamics of the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), any other statistical/physical properties can be described by Schrodinger equation?

I am also asking if any physical system can be second quantized?

Comment: Aside from the complex aspect, isn't the SE a [reaction-diffusion-type equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_system)?

Comment: @KyleKanos true, but the imaginary part gives some generalization, I guess, so it should be also describe more general problem.

Comment: Madelung's hydrodynamical interpretation could also be an idea.